How do I prevent function-data overlap when multiple independent threads are trying to execute 1 function?
I am trying to create a depth tree in c# (.NET CORE 3.1) for a chess program. I use a branching technique that uses multiple functions, but 1 function is used very often. The process goes
repeat to a depth of 5 ->(move -> top 3 moves after that move)
The issue is that I am getting random runtime binding on a null reference exceptions in functions at random points in the function, even after lines of code that use the same data.
The only explanation that I can think of is data overlap inside of the function itself, during the functions execution. This would cause c# to first free up space, making the value null, then writing new data into that space. And during that time if a line of code in the function calls for that value while c# is writing data into there, it returns a runtime binding on a null reference exception.
The issue is also that multiple independent threads that can't communicate with each other are trying to use 1 function at the same time.
First I tried to lock every thread using an objectLock. Then I rewrote the code to use async functions and Task instead of direct threads. Then I made all of the functions in question non-static. The same problem happens even after I have tried all of that.
The only loose pattern I have seen is that it happens most often when the function is calling itself, but this isn't 100% of the time. I am trying not to write new functions just for the recursive calls as that might make the code feel bloated.

If your program runs OK on one thread, and doesn't run OK on multiple threads, it means that you have race conditions and/or concurrent access on non-thread-safe shared state. We can't say much more without seeing your code. Is it possible to include in the question a minimal and reproducible example that demonstrates the problematic behavior?

"I made all of the functions in question non-static" You should get into the habit of doing that anyway. static is the enemy of multi-threading, and static is the enemy of testing.

I found out that my thread locks were incorrect, I was always doing local locks and not global, after refactoring the code and threads, it works now
